Proving that the set of limit points of a set is closed directly
I'm working on Baby Rudin chapter 2's exercises and I'm stuck on problem #6, in particular the first part where he asks to prove that the set of limit points E', of a set E, is closed.
Here's my attempt:
Let E be a set and E' the set of limit points of E. Let p be any limit point of E'.
By definition, we know $$ \forall r> 0, N^*_r(p) \cap E' \neq \emptyset$$
Since $$ \bar{E} = E \cup E'$$
it follows that
$$\forall r> 0, N^*_r(p) \cap \bar{E} \neq \emptyset $$
Thus, p is a limit point of $\bar{E}$. Hence $p \in \bar{E} \rightarrow p \in E \cup E' $.
If $p \in E'$  we are done. Now, suppose $p \in E$. Toward a contradiction suppose $p$ is not a limit point of $E$. Then $\exists r > 0$ such that $N^*_r(p) \cap E = \emptyset$.
Not sure how to continue from here. Also, Note that $N^*_r(p)$ represents the punctured neighborhood.
edit:
OK I think I got it:
Let $p$ be a limit point of $E'$. Then, we know $\forall r_p > 0 
,\exists q \in N^{*}_{r_p} \cap E' \neq \emptyset$. Since $q \in E'$ q is limit point of $E$. So $\forall r_q > 0, N^{*}_{r_q}(q) \cap E \neq \emptyset$. In particular, since each neighborhood is an open set, we know $\exists r_q < r_p$ such that $N^{*}_{r_q}(q) \subset N^{*}_{r_p}(p)$. Since $N^{*}_{r_q}(q) \cap E \neq \emptyset$ it follows that $N^{*}_{r_p}(p) \cap E \neq \emptyset$ so $p$ is limit point of $E$ and therefore $p \in E'$ as desired.

This is a mega-dupe https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Set+of+limit+points+is+closed See for instance $E'$ is closed, where $E'$ is the set of limit points of $E$

I don't know how to continue your twisted logical way, but at the begining, let
$$q\in N^*(p)\cap E'\neq\emptyset$$
Then, since $q\in E'$ and $N^*(p)$ is a nbd of $q$, $N^*(p)\cap E\neq\emptyset$ for any nbd $N(p)$ of $p$. So, $p\in E'$.

so like this? Suppose $p$ is in $E$. Since $p$ is limit point of $E'$ we know that $\forall r > 0, N^_r \cap E' \neq \emptyset$. Let $q \neq p$ be a point in this intersection. Then, we know $q$ is also a limit point of $E'$ so there must some neighborhood of $q$ that intersects $E$ at a point other than $q$. In particular there exists $N^_r(q) \subset N^_r(p)$. Since $N^_r(q) \cap E \neq \emptyset$ it follows that $N^*_r(p) \cap E \neq \emptyset $ thus p is a limit point of $E$

@user8083 why do you start supposing $p\in E$?

it was established that p was in the closure of E. So it must in either E or E'. if p is in E' we're done. The argument above would be addressing the case #2.

@user8083 I think it is not necessary. Also, this is not how you started your attempt.

Yeah i tried going for a contradiction. instead I just went direct this time around. Also p being in the closure E was used since E being closed set was a result that Rudin proved earlier in the chapter.

To show $p$ is a limit point of $E$, we must show that for any $r>0$ there is $q \in E$ with $d(q,p) < r$. Well, since $p$ is a limit point of $E'$, choose $s \in E'$ with $0 < d(p,s) < r/2$, and since $s$ is a limit point of $E$ choose $q \in E$ with $d(q,s) < d(p,s)$ (in particular $q \ne p$). Can you finish from here?

ok here's my continuation of my proof. Instead of doing it by contradiction lets just do it directly. Suppose $p$ is in $E$. Since $p$ is limit point of $E'$ we know that $\forall r > 0, N^_r \cap E' \neq \emptyset$. Let $q \neq p$ be a point in this intersection. Then, we know $q$ is also a limit point of $E'$ so there must some neighborhood of $q$ that intersects $E$ at a point other than $q$. In particular there exists $N^_r(q) \subset N^_r(p)$. Since $N^_r(q) \cap E \neq \emptyset$ it follows that $N^*_r(p) \cap E \neq \emptyset $ thus p is a limit point of $E$

What is the reason for the downvote?

+1 Folks rarely explain their downvotes, unfortunately,

I don't know Baby Rudin. But $p$ is a limit point of $E$ means there is a sequence $p_n\in E$ such that $p_n\neq p$ and $p_n\to p.$ (*) In particular, for any $\varepsilon>0$ the set of $m$ such that $p_m$ is within $\varepsilon$ of $p$ is infinite.
And the set $E'$ of limit points is closed if every convergent sequence of points $q_n$ in $E'$ converges to a point in $E'$.
Let $q_n\to q$ where $q_n\in E'$, We must show $q$ is in $E'$. We can assume $q_n$ is within $\tfrac{1}{n}$ of $q$. Pick $q^*_{n}\in E$ such that $q^*_{n}\neq q_n,q$ and $q^*_{n}$ is within $\tfrac{1}{n}$ of $q_n$. This is possible by (*).
By the triangle inequality $q^*_n$ is within $\tfrac{2}{n}$ of $q$ hence $q$ is a limit point of $E.$
